# MSYS2 paste problem when pasting multiple and long lines

Tags: windows, cygwin, clipboard, msys2

I have an issue with recent versions of [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) that I didn't have with older versions.

I often paste a large number of commands, some of which are longer that the console width. There are also sometimes multiline commands in there (e.g. shell `if` stuff with the `fi` several lines later). But I do make sure there are no tabs in there to avoid autocompletion from kicking in.

In old MSYS2 I could just paste everything and the commands would start right away.

In newer MSYS2 after pasting it is apparently waiting for another Enter before starting.

But what's worse: the data pasted isn't intact. Sometimes pieces are missing, sometimes it gets truncated, sometimes both.

I have reproduced this on Windows 10 and Windows 11.

I also tried running `msys2.exe` as well as others like `mingw64.exe`, and I even tried running `sh.exe` from [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console).

Is there some kind of setting or environment variable to get the old paste behaviour back?

*UPDATE*

- Also tried with Windows Terminal
- Tried pasting from different source (Notepad instead of Notepad++)
- Tried changing copied source (in Notepad++) to different line endings (CR, LF, CR+LF)

No improvement.

Additionally I noticed sometimes part of the beginning of the copied text are pasted last. So it's not just a matter of missing pieces - the contents get thrown around during paste...

Comment: I also had issues with garbled text on paste. I suggest filing bugs to https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues (one for garbling, another for missing auto-enter).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I already logged a case (https://github.com/msys2/msys2-runtime/issues/75). Did you ever manage to git rid of the problem?

Comment: Nope, I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to resolve this issue in [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) or [Console2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), but when using [mintty](https://mintty.github.io/) from [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) the following fixes the paste problem:

```
bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste off'
```

As [mintty](https://mintty.github.io/) is not a console program (in the Windows application sense) this solution can't be made to work with [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) or [Console2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), but it is possible with [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/).

Comment: To anyone wondering what "bracketed paste" is. Apparently it sends special escape sequences before and after pasted text, allowing programs to distinguish pasted text.